# MYSQL how to get next auto increment when inserting with select

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, insert-into

I have two tables who's structure is identical, but the content is different. The first column of each table is an auto increment id.

What I am trying to do is insert *some* rows from one table into the other. However, the id column should set automatically in the target table and not be copied from the source.

So far I am using something like:

```
INSERT INTO table_1
    SELECT
       id,
       column_2,
       column_3,
       column_4
    FROM table_2
    WHERE column_4 = 'a value'
```

I cannot just select the ID from table 2 as shown above as this creates duplicate ids in table 1.

I have tried replacing 'id' with: `(SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM table_1) AS id`.  That gets the correct id, but doesn't increment it for each row to be inserted.

I have tried `(SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA_TABLES WHERE SCHEMA_TABLE = 'table_1') AS id` but that just fails saying 'Unable to resolve column AUTO_INCREMENT'

I have tried `LAST_INSERT_ID() as id`. This actually worked the first time I run the statement, but further attempts fail with the message 'Duplicate entry 875 for key PRIMARY'

Finally, I have tried to just leave the column out altogether but i then get an error message saying the number of columns do not match.

Can anyone shed any light onto this? I should point out that I need pure MySQL. I am not in the context of PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the columns to insert to, then you can leave it out:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (column_2, column_3, column_4)
  SELECT column_2, column_3, column_4
    FROM table_2
    WHERE column_4 = 'a value'
```

Comment: Ah.  With 74 columns I was hoping to avoid that, but if it works, it is no big deal. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Typhoon101 Yes, it gets quite cumbersome easily. Much nicer on some other engines where you could just query a sequence :/

Answer (score 0):

You can specify all the columns except `ID` in `INSERT` statement, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (column_2, column_3, column_4)
    SELECT
       column_2,
       column_3,
       column_4
    FROM table_2
    WHERE column_4 = 'a value'
```

As `ID` is auto generated in table2, it will automatically get the value.